# Compare 2 variables with 2 variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I just started studying Javascript and I'm trying to create a mini-game.
I want to get the vocation of a character comparing if his health skill and attack skill are bigger than magic and speed, then he's a knight.
But what I'm trying is not working.

```
if (hp1 && at1 > mg1 && sp1){
    document.querySelector('.badgesContainer .knight').style.display = 'block'
}
else{
    document.querySelector('.badgesContainer .druid').style.display = 'none'
    document.querySelector('.badgesContainer .knight').style.display = 'none'
    document.querySelector('.badgesContainer .paladin').style.display = 'none'
    document.querySelector('.badgesContainer .sorcerer').style.display = 'none'  
}
```

Comment: This `hp1 && at1 > mg1 && sp1` actually means just: *if hp is truthy and at1 is bigger than mg1 and sp1 is truthy*.

Comment: What you probably want is: `hp1 > mg1 && hp1 > sp1 && at1 > mg1 && at1 > sp1`.

Comment: I'd add a `vocation` property. It makes things easier down the road.

Comment: It depends on the variable types. If they're numbers, you can do (based on your literal requirement): `if ((hp1 + at1) > (mg1 + sp1))`, which simply adds hp and attack, then checks if that's greater than the total for magic and speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the hp1 and at1 then compare it to mg1 and sp1

```
if ( (hp1 + at1) > (mg1 + sp1)){
    document.querySelector('.badgesContainer .knight').style.display = 'block'
}
else{
    document.querySelector('.badgesContainer .druid').style.display = 'none'
    document.querySelector('.badgesContainer .knight').style.display = 'none'
    document.querySelector('.badgesContainer .paladin').style.display = 'none'
    document.querySelector('.badgesContainer .sorcerer').style.display = 'none'  
}
```